# Opening DataURI in new browser tab with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, tabs, data-uri

Given some DataURI such as `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,Hello%20World`, is it possible to open this URI in a new tab in the same browser window? I know that this is possible for addresses such as `https://www.google.com` by using the code

```
var win = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
win.focus();
```

inside of some click event listener function. BUT the following code does **not** work as expected:

```
var win = window.open('data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,Hello%20World', '_blank');
win.focus();
```

Instead of opening up a new tab with a blank page containing the text "Hello World", a new tab opens up which is totally blank and the URL space contains `about:blank` instead of the dataURI `data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,Hello%20World` as would be the case if I opened the dataURI manually. What is going on here? Why are data URI and the http address being treated differently? How can I rectify this? Note that it is important that I use javascript for this. Although this toy example doesn't require it, my actual project involves dynamically generated dataURI strings.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2017/11/27/blocking-top-level-navigations-data-urls-firefox-59/

Comment: Interesting. I tried my program on Firefox and am NOT encountering the issue. It seems to only crop up in Chrome.